# Is MSG soluble in oil?

Tags: oil, msg

I know that salt is not soluble in oil. I've tried seasoning oil with it and the salt never dissolved. I was wondering if MSG behaves the same way as salt in oil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Monosodium glutamate is a salt, and like most salts is essentially insoluble in oil.

Comment: Glutamic acid is soluble at 0.00035g/100g ethanol (25°C). The sodium salt will be similar. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glutamic_acid The stuff is highly polar, and oils are highly nonpolar. They will not mix well together, even the *salts* of glutamate as you are asking about.